# CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR returning the wrong directory

Tags: compilation, cmake

I have the following folder structure:

```
- SomeApp
  * CMakeLists.txt
  * source.cpp
  - cmake-build-debug
  - protobuf
    * CMakeLists.txt
    * file.proto
```

In my root CMakeLists.txt file is written:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(SomeApp)

message("Root Dir: ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}")

ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(protobuf)
```

And in my ./protobuf/ CMakeLists.txt is for testing just written:

```
message("Protobuf Dir: ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}")
```

During compiling, I get as output:

```
Root Dir: /home/<...>/SomeApp/cmake-build-debug
Protobuf Dir: /home/<...>/SomeApp/cmake-build-debug
```

According to https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR.html, the actual output should be:

```
Root Dir: /home/<...>/SomeApp/
Protobuf Dir: /home/<...>/SomeApp/protobuf/
```

What is going wrong with my cmake settings?

Comment: Are you sure the output is not Protobuf Dir: /home/<...>/SomeApp/cmake-build-debug/protobuf? Without the trailing protobuf, I would be puzzled.

Comment: cmake-build-debug is your build directory. Everything is put there, and the current binary dir is always below the build directory. I am not sure you got this or whether is part of your question (search for out-of-source build for more information)

Comment: I've given your example a try and get - as expected - `Root Dir: .../SomeApp/cmake-build-debug` and `Protobuf Dir: .../SomeApp/cmake-build-debug/protobuf`. So with the given example your problem can't be reproduced and is definitely missing something crucial.

Answer (score 2):

In your case the variable `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR` displays the path to a subdirectory of your build directory `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR`.

Assume your code is in `/home/myname/SomeApp` and your are in the sibling folder `/home/myname/cmake-build-debug`.

- The value of `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR` is `/home/myname/cmake-build-debug`.
- The value of `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR` is `/home/myname/cmake-build-debug`.
- In this case `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR` is equal to `CMAKE_CURRENT_DIR`.

Extending the example:
You have a CMakeLists.txt in the subfolder `unittests`.

- `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR` is `/home/myname/cmake-build-debug`.
- `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR` is
  `/home/myname/cmake-build-debug/unittests`.

On Linux you can perform the following commands to review this:

```
cd /home/myname/SomeApp
cd ..
mkdir cmake-build-debug
cmake ../SomeApp
make
```

Comment: I guess you missmatch `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR` and `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR`